# JQuery Append To Textbox When Typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 textboxes, I want to create something like this: When I type to textbox1, it will duplicate to textbox3, and when I type to textbox2, it will append to textbox3 with a delimiter ( - ).

For example, if I write STACK to textbox1, textbox3 will result STACK, then if I wrote down textbox2 with OVERFLOW, textbox3 value is: STACK-OVERFLOW

Here's my code at fiddle:

```js
$(function() {                                      
    $("#text1").keyup(function() {                 
        $('#text3').val(this.value);                 
    });
    $("#text2").keyup(function() {                 
        $('#text3').val.append('-'+this.value);                 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />
<input type="text" id="text3" />
```

Anyone can fix my code?

Comment: What is the problem or error you are getting??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {                                      
    var text1value , text2value;
    $("#text1").keyup(function() {                 
        text1value = $(this).val();
        $('#text3').val(text1value);                 
    });
    $("#text2").keyup(function() {                 
        text2value = $(this).val();
        $('#text3').val(text1value+'-'+text2value);                 
    });
});
```

Comment: @CrossVander you welcome ..you may need a little bit of if statement as well to check if empty of textboxes but Its simple to do ..  Good Luck

Comment: sure, I've just done that too, because when I implement it to my project it gives a little error. But it's working fine now. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to check also if text2 is empty so you don't have to concatenate the '-' in that case.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkeuLjgc/3/)

```
$(function() {                                      
    $("#text1").keyup(function() {
        var text2 = $('#text2').val();
        var temp = $(this).val();
        if (text2 != '') {
            temp = $(this).val()+'-'+text2;
        }
        $('#text3').val(temp);                 
    });
    $("#text2").keyup(function() {   
        var temp = $('#text1').val()+'-'+$(this).val();
        $('#text3').val(temp);                 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {                                      
    $("#text1").keyup(function() {                 
        $('#text3').val(this.value);                 
    });
    $("#text2").keyup(function(e) {                 
        $('#text3').val(function(index, val) {
            return $("#text1").val() + "-" + e.target.value;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
This should do it

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />
<input type="text" id="text3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/6qojd9L4/

```
$(function() {                                      
    $("#text1").keyup(function() {                 
        $('#text3').val(this.value + '-' + $('#text2').val());                 
    });
    $("#text2").keyup(function() {                 
        $('#text3').val($('#text1').val() + '-'+this.value);                 
    });
});
```